# Keyboard layout switch (Ctrl+Shift) in a new xorg

Tags: xorg, keyboard-layout, xkb

I've been using similar config for years:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "keyboard-all"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"
    Driver "evdev"
    Option "XkbLayout" "us,ru,de"
    Option "XkbVariant" ",winkeys,"
    Option "XkbOptions" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,grp:ctrl_shift_toggle"
EndSection
```

After updating to a newer version of my distro both right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> switch keyboard layout only in one direction us -> ru -> de. It used to work like this before:

- Right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>: us -> ru -> de
- Left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>: us -> de -> ru (reverse order)

Is there any way to restore the old behavior?

Comment: Which file is this?

Comment: @NickolaiLeschov a config file with any name in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`. Mine in particular is named `90-keyboard-layout.conf`.

Comment: I don't have a directory named `xorg.conf.d`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so here is where the story starts: https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42931
It seems that someone didn't like the old behavior so it was changed to one-directional.

Although man-page in my xkeyboard-config-2.6 doesn't have all the options supported, there are _bidir switch options, which you can use. Thus to restore the old behavior your config (or corresponding setxkbmap command) should look like this:

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "keyboard-all"
    MatchIsKeyboard "on"
    Driver "evdev"
    Option "XkbLayout" "us,ru,de"
    Option "XkbVariant" ",winkeys,"
    Option "XkbOptions" "terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp,grp:ctrl_shift_toggle_bidir"
EndSection
```